# linux gnome, how to disable Ctrl+. shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I am using Manajaro Linux with the GNOME environment on Wayland. Since the last update there's a weird new shortcut under Ctrl+.

I was using Ctrl+. for a long time in VSCode where it shows me Quick Fix suggestions. But right now it is not working anymore, in the VSCode and everywhere else this combination makes an 'e' character appear, but it's not actually an 'e' char, it doesn't get saved as a text instead it disappears if I type anything in and click enter or escape. I have no idea what is it but it's very irritating since my workflow is suddenly disrupted.

I was looking for this keybind in the settings under custom shortcuts but there's nothing like that there.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this? It's very annoying

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found out that this has to do with a new emoji hotkey from [IBus](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IBus). You can remap it with `ibus-setup`.

Comment: Thank you for this so much, it works now. Also f*** emoji

Answer (score 5):

I want to add some details.

1. Command `ibus-setup` opens a window.
2. At the `Emoji` tab you will see `<Control>period;<Control>semicolon`
3. Click three dots on the right-hand side `...`
4. Then select `<Control>period` and delete it. Or change it if you want.
5. Now your `ctrl + .` must be working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu after upgrading to version 22.04. Just adapting the settings in `ibus-setup` did not solve the issue.

After reading [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125726/how-to-disable-ctrl-shift-e-keybinding-from-showing-eeeee-and-loading-emoji-opti#1302814) I was able to disable the emoji input feature by reinstalling ibus and then tweaking in ibus-config:

```
sudo apt remove ibus
sudo apt install ibus
ibus-config
```